# Extract names of all .php3 files within a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a file that has code in it listing many other php files - I want to extract out all the *unique* names of the .php3 files that are within this file.

I have used the following which works somewhat:

```
grep -Po '".*php3"' test.php3 | cut -d \" -f2
```

***It does not work where some of the files are also listed in an array e.g.***

```
array("test1.php3","ltest2.php3","test3.php3","test4.php3");
```

What should I add to the command ?  IS there a better solution ?

Thanks

Comment: `grep -Po '".*php3"'`  -> `grep -Po '[^"]*php3'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
s='array("test1.php3","ltest2.php3","test3.php3","test4.php3");'
echo "$s" | grep -oP '\w+\.php3'
test1.php3
ltest2.php3
test3.php3
test4.php3
```